# URL Rewrite web.config add fake folder between domain and pages

Tags: azure, iis, web-config

Just a simple question. 
I have a domain *website.com*, and this page have specific pages named with country code.

- website.com/**uk**
- website.com/**fr**
- website.com/**us**
- ...

I've created rule on my web.config file with the following URl rewrite:

```
 <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url= "^([^/]+)/?$"/>          
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="ContactUs.php?lang={R:1}" />
  </rule>
```

Pages are generated in PHP, variable called *lang* is used to display the choosen page and is present in URL.

I would like to add **"contact/"** between my domain and pages.

- website.com/**contact**/uk
- website.com/**contact**/fr
- ...

I have the following rule :

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="contact([^/]+)/?$"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="ContactUs.php?lang={R:1}"/>
 </rule>
```

I anyone can explain me what did I didn't understand, 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is slightly wrong.

```
^contact\/([a-z]+)\/?$
```

That should do what you need it to, assuming all your country codes are letters only.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to first redirect website.com/uk to website.com/contact/uk and rewrite website.com/contact/uk to ContactUs.php?lang=uk?

if you wnats to do like that you could use below URL rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.sample2.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/[a-zA-Z]+$" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/contact{C:0}" />
 </rule>
              <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/contact/([a-z]+)" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="ContactUs.php?lang={C:1}" />
 </rule>
```